# Return true if the point lies within the boundaries of the rectangle

Tags: java, rectangles

I'm needing to find the point lies within the boundaries of the rectangle or its border. The code I have so far is not finding if the point lies within the boundaries of the rectangle or its border. Please help.

Here is what I have so far and this is the only part that isn't executing correctly.

```
public static boolean contains(Rectangle r, Point p)
{
   // TODO - you need to implement this. May want to use isInBetween
    return p.x >= r.x && p.y >= r.y && p.x < r.x + r.width && p.y < r.y + r.height;             
}
```

Here is the rest of my code:

```
package assignment;

import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;

public class Assignment6 {

    //this is just sample code demonstrating aliasing
    public static void aliasing1()
    {
        Point pt1=new Point(10,10);
        Point pt2=new Point(5,5);

        Point alias=pt1;
        alias.x+=pt2.x;

        alias=pt2;
        alias.y+=5;

        int sumX=pt1.x+pt2.x;
        int sumY=pt1.y+pt2.y;

        System.out.println("sumX= "+sumX+ " -sumY= "+sumY);
    }

    // more sample code
    public static void playWithRectangles(){
        Rectangle r=new Rectangle(10, 10, 5, 7);
        System.out.println(r.x);
    }
    /* Examples */

    /*
     * A point is to the left of another if its x coordinate is less than the other
     */
    public static boolean isToTheLeft(Point p1, Point p2)
    {
        return p1.x < p2.x;
    }

    /*
     * A point is to the right of another if its x coordinate is bigger than the other
     */
    public static boolean isToTheRight(Point p1, Point p2)
    {
        // TODO - you need to implement this
        return p1.x > p2.x;
    }

    /*
     * We use 'screen coordinates', with y=0 being at the top of the screen and growing downwards
     * so a point is above another if its y coordinate is less
     */
    public static boolean isAbove(Point p1, Point p2)
    {
        return p1.y<p2.y;
    }

    /* isBelow returns true if the first point is below the second one (a point is below another if its y coordinate is bigger)
     */
    public static boolean isBelow(Point p1, Point p2)
    {
        // TODO - you need to implement this
        return p1.y>p2.y;
    }

    // Example - calculate area of a rectangle
    public static int getArea(Rectangle r)
    {
        return r.width*r.height;
    }


    // Example - grow a rectangle's width and height by a factor. Notice we're modifying the rectangle
    public static void growRectangle(Rectangle r, int factor)
    {
        r.width *= factor;
        r.height *= factor;
    }


    /* The rectangle has the top-left coordinates (in screen coordinates, y=0 is top, y grows down)
     * So the bottom-right coordinate can be calculated by adding the width and height to x and y, respectively
     */
    public Point getBottomRightCorner(Rectangle r)
    {
        return new Point(r.x+r.width, r.y+r.height);
    }

    /*
     * Returns the center of the rectangle. The center is obtained by adding half the width and half the height to the x and y coordinates respectively
     * Round DOWN (if needed) when calculating the center.
     */
    public static Point getCenter(Rectangle r)
    {
        return new Point(r.x+r.width/2, r.y+r.height/2);
    }

    /**
     * Example Returns true if x is between low and high (inclusive)
     */
    public static boolean isInBetween(int x, int low, int high)
    {
        return x>=low && x<=high;
    }

    /**
     * Returns true if the rectangle contains the point; that is, if the point lies within the boundaries of the rectangle
     * If the point is exactly in the border we still return true.
     * @param r - the rectangle
     * @param p - the point
     * @return true if the point lies within the rectangle or on its border
     */
    public static boolean contains(Rectangle r, Point p)
    {
        // TODO - you need to implement this. May want to use isInBetween
        return p.x >= r.x && p.y >= r.y && p.x < r.x + r.width && p.y < r.y + r.height;     
    }

    /* Person example */
    public static void usingPerson() {
        Person p1=new Person("Orlando","Karam",40); // we construct with first, last names, age
        System.out.println(p1.getFirstName()); // would print Orlando
        System.out.println(p1.getLastName()); // would print Karam
        System.out.println(p1.getAge()); // would print 40

    }
    /* Example - two people are relatives if they have the same last name :) */
    public boolean areRelatives(Person p1, Person p2)
    {
        return p1.getLastName().equals(p2.getLastName());
    }

    /* Example creating a description for a person, with name and age*/
    public String getDescription(Person p)
    {
        return p.getFirstName()+" "+p.getLastName()+" is "+p.getAge()+" years old";
    }

    /* return true if the persons' first and last name and age are equal */
    public static boolean personEquals(Person p1, Person p2)
    {
        // TODO - you need to implement this
        return p1.getFirstName().equals(p2.getFirstName()) && p1.getLastName().equals(p2.getLastName());
    }

    /* returns a person's full name, composed of the first name, a space and the last name, as in
     * Orlando Karam
     */
    public static String getFullName(Person p)
    {
        // TODO - you need to implement this
        return p.getFirstName()+" "+p.getLastName();
    }

    /* returns a 'formal' full name, composed of the last name, a comma, a space and the first name, as in
     * Karam, Orlando
     */
    public static String getFormalFullName(Person p)
    {
        // TODO - you need to implement this
        return p.getLastName()+","+" "+p.getFirstName();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // you can use this as you wish to test or exercise your function. Not graded.
    }

}
```

Here is the code that executes the Contains method. It is suppose to give me 15 points if the point is found, but right now it isn't giving me any points.
Points will be awarded to the correct answer! Thanks in advance.

```
@Grade(points = 15)
    @Test
    public void testContains() {
        Assert.assertTrue(Assignment6.contains(new Rectangle(0, 0, 10, 10), new Point(5, 5)));
        Assert.assertTrue(Assignment6.contains(new Rectangle(0, 0, 10, 10), new Point(0, 0)));
        Assert.assertTrue(Assignment6.contains(new Rectangle(0, 0, 10, 10), new Point(0, 10)));
        Assert.assertFalse(Assignment6.contains(new Rectangle(0, 0, 10, 10), new Point(11, 5)));
        Assert.assertFalse(Assignment6.contains(new Rectangle(0, 0, 10, 10), new Point(5, 15)));
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static boolean contains(Rectangle r, Point p)
{
   // TODO - you need to implement this. May want to use isInBetween
    return p.x >= r.x && p.y >= r.y && p.x <= r.x + r.width && p.y < =r.y + r.height;             
}
```

or, as mentioned in comment, you can use IsBetween

```
public static boolean contains(Rectangle r, Point p)
{
        return Assignment6.isBetween(p.x,r.x,r.x+r.width) && Assignment6.isBetween(p.y,r.y,r.y+r.height);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!
My Java is rusty, but I got this rest of it right though other than this part.